# ¿como obtengo el contexto de mi canvas en vue? me dice el error de "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')"

Tags: vue.js, canvas

Lei por ahi que no se renderiza mi canvas en el dom a la hora de que la variable "contexto" toma como valor el objeto que arroja el metodo canvas.getContext('2d') (osea a la hora de declarar: `const contexto = canvas.getContext('2d')` ), estuve probando de distintas formas pero no encuentro una que me resuelva mi problema, necesito tener la variable contexto con el objeto CanvasRenderingContext2D { ... } y poder exportarla a otros componentesy tambien a otros archivos .js de mi proyecto donde tengo clases para poder dibujar elementos dentro de mi canvas, se agradece la ayuda

Comment: y canvas como esta definido... y eso donde esta escrito en tu script de vue....

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: pude exportar la variable contexto con un export let context, el cual lo pude recibir en todos los archivos, pero los metodos del objeto CanvasRenderingContext2D no me dejan utilizar, ya que me tira el error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'fillStyle')` al ejecutar ctx.fillStyle

Comment: yo no se sobre canvas en vue.. pero como vue maneja un dom virtual, capaz necesitas una implementacion de canvas para vue?